# Why is my Restangular save() making wrong put call.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

So here is my JS code:

```
api.allServiceProviders.one(routeParams.spid).get().then(function(response){
    $scope.service_provider = response

})

$scope.editServiceProvider = function(){
    $scope.service_provider.save().then(function(response){

    })
}
```

The first API call returns the correct response by making a call to /serviceprovider/14

When I get into the edit function then the save call makes a put to /serviceprovider/14/14

For the love of god, I am not ab;t to figure what I did wrong. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Your URL building is a bit off. I assume that `allServiceProviders` is a collection, so you use the [get](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#collection-methods) method of a collection. If this is the case, you should be fine when specifying the id as a parameter for the get method.

```
api.allServiceProviders.get(routeParams.spid).then(function(response){
    $scope.service_provider = response

})

$scope.editServiceProvider = function(){
    $scope.service_provider.save().then(function(response){

    })
}
```

Comment: Right. I refactored by Restangular configuration to make this work. But thanks a lot for the info. Will go this route if i face any more troubles later.